# Using variables in a different method?

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am writing a hangman game in java and I have come across a problem. I have a method that chooses a random word from an array and stores it in a variable. Now in the method where the game is run, how would I use the random word variable?

```
public class Hangman {

public static Scanner qwe = new Scanner(in);

public static void word(){
    String words[]= {"Cat","dog"};

    int i = words.length;

    Random rng = new Random();
    int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word

    gameStart();
}



public static void gameStart(){    //Asks user if they wish to start
    out.println("Welcome to my hangman game!");
    out.println("Would you like to begin?");
    String asd = qwe.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if (asd.contains("y")){
        game();
    }
    else if (asd.contains("n")){
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        out.println("Not a recognized answer");
        gameStart();
    }
}

public static void game(){
    out.println(choice);    //Trying to print out random word varible
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    out.println("HangMan Game made by Ryan Hosford\n");
    gameStart();
}
}
```

Comment: One possibility would be to make your **word** function return a value. Info on return ca be found [in the Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use directly one `method variables` in other `methods` , because they are `local` to that `method`.

You can just pass them to that method. or make that method to `return` required `value` and call where ever you  want.

You are no where using the `word()` method.You can do return the `value`

```
public static int word(){
    String words[]= {"Cat","dog"};

    int i = words.length;

    Random rng = new Random();
    int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word
    return choice;

}
```

Then, make use of above method in `game()` method

```
    public static void game(){    //Asks user if they wish to start
        int choice= word();   <-- call word that gives you choice
        // so now you have choice here. you can use it now.
         out.println(choice); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i was wondering if you could clear something up. I understand what you are saying, but i was wondering why you used int returnedChoice = word(); in the gameStart() method. I haven't written out the game yet, i just wanted to see how i would go about doing the whole 'using a variable in a different method' thing. In the game, i will be using the choice variable in the game() method. Would i do the same thing as you did in the gameStart() in the game() method? In the game() method i will be checking if the user's input matches any of the letters of the chosen word.

Comment: Thanks again for the help and i'm sorry if my question isn't very clear.

Comment: The concept is just calling that method, where we need. Ryan, I just edited my post with your doubt. Please have a look and let me know If you need any further clarification.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, i have run into a problem. Everything works fine, except for the fact that it returns the number value for choice, and not the string. Is their an easy fix for this? Or would it be easier to use a different class or something like that? I'm sorry about all these questions, i am new to java and haven't learned anything about different classes and how to call them. If it would be better to make a separate class for choosing a random item out of the string, could you show me how to do that? Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a function it is local to that function. If you want to allow access to the variable you will have to essentially declare it such a way that every function in that context will be able to access it. You can either pass the variable as function argument with nested calling or declare the variable with access modifier such as `static`.

BY Making the `words[]= {"Cat","dog"}` static and call gameStart(String word) with chosen word by changing `gameStart()` method signature to `gameStart(String word)` :

`public static String words[]= {"Cat","dog"};`

```
public static int word(){
    int i = words.length;

    Random rng = new Random();
    int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word

    gameStart(words[choice]);
}


public static void gameStart(String chosenWord){
//......... your code
 if (asd.contains("y")){
    game(chosenWord);
}
//....... your code

} 

 public static void game(String chosenWord)
 {
     System.out.println(chosenWord);
 }
```

**Or**, Adding a static String `chosenWord` as follows:

```
public static String chosenWord = ""; // using a static variable chosenWord
public static String words[]= {"Cat","dog"};
public static void word(){
        int i = words.length;

        Random rng = new Random();
        int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word
        chosenWord = words[choice] ; // chosen word assigning
        gameStart();
    }

public static void game()
{
  System.out.println(chosenWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All variables on the `word()` method are local variables, which have scope only within the method in which they're declared.

To increase the longevity of the selection, make a field (static for convenience):

```
static String word;

public static void word(){
    ...
    word = words[rng.nextInt(words.length)];
```

Then the `word` field (variable) will be visible to code in the other method.